# Is there a way to determine the current Outlook activity level?

Tags: c#, outlook-2007, outlook-addin

I am working on an Outlook 2007 Add-in in C# (VS2008) and we want to send some background email items  only when Outlook is not busy doing something else.  Is there a .net way to see if Outlook is busy doing other things (perhaps due to other add-ins or the like taking up CPU cycles)?

Alternately, is there a way to send emails such that they never appear in the Outbox?  We need a method that would not require any additional software be installed.

Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 0):

All I can think of is to monitor the OST file datetime.  Not to good, but it is something.  How have you done on this?